# Java/Class Path Difficulty

Tags: java, eclipse

I know it shows this question has been asked before, but this seems rather specific. I have the class path set up right, or else Eclipse couldn't compile code from the same project/package, right? So, when I try to run some of my classes, I get this error message:

Error: Could not find or load main class

I try to move it to a different package? I get this dialog box:

[image: Error dialog box]

I try to move it manually into the folder in the path? It gives me the same dialog box, and then it disappears. It's not in Eclipse. It's not in the folder. It's gone. (Thank GOD I backed it up on GitHub).

Anybody know what's going on with this...?

**EDIT:**

I don't know if this will help, but I've got two Projects. One I use specifically for copying code out of my book (it helps me to understand the explanations). The other, I have for experimenting and play. There are a BUNCH of classes. I'm wondering if the IDE is just getting too bogged down with much information??

I also recently downloaded Android Studio, so...maybe that could have messed up my path/classpath...?

Comment: Are you maybe trying to run a class which doesn't contain a `public static void main(String[] args)` method?

Comment: @Aaron Nope! The class that disappeared contained methods for the main, but I wasn't trying to run it. I'm trying to run the client.

Comment: What does "run the client" mean?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Sorry if I'm using the wrong lingo - still new lol. The client is the class I'm using to call the other class' methods.

Comment: Your issue can't be diagnosed without more information. The class you're trying to run must have `public static void main(String[] args)`. This is the entry point for a java application. If it doesn't have a `main` method, it will show the error you saw, `Error: Could not find or load main class`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider It has everything you mentioned, and I'm still getting that message.

Answer (score -1):

Your project buildpath might be setup correctly, but maybe your run configuration for your classes does not include the default classpath?. When you typically right click on a class file that has a main method and select 'Run As..Java Application' it should use the default buildpath for your project as the classpath. Try running your classes that way and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: That didn't work. Gives me the same error message in the console :-/

Answer (score -1):

Check your `Default output folder`: Right click on your project -> Java Build Path -> Source tab : Default output folder.

It should be something like: [yourprojectname]/bin

Then check your .classpath file: it should contain both your src and output folders. It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

You can also check the Error Log view (Show View -> Error Log ), to see what is causing the NPE in the Java Builder?

Comment: I did find something weird in the error log:

"Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Kevin Frederiksen'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page."

Comment: That is unlikely because you have a problem with your Java Builder, not with Git. I suggest you empty your eclipse log file and then after reproducing the problem check the ./metadata/.log file in your workspace folder. You should find something related to Java Builder.

Comment: yup, all started two days ago. Several that say, "Error in JDT core during AST creation", and then "Errors occurred during the build." And "Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'Experimenting'."

Comment: Checked the ./metadata/.log file, and it's giving me the same messages, with long lists of exceptions.